# Do not use keys in dictionary as index when converting to dataframe using pandas from_dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ordereddictionary

```
odict = OrderedDict([ ('dub', ['8084', 'command']),
      ('lhr',['8083','command']),
      ('ams',['8085','command']),])

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(odict, orient='index')
print(df)
```

I have the above OrderedDict and command to convert to dataframe. I would like the keys in the dict to be used as data in a column rather than being used as the index. It's printing out like this below.

```
        0        1
dub  8084  command
lhr  8083  command
ams  8085  command
```

However I would like it to print like this using what I think is called RangeIndex.

```
    0     1        2
0 dub  8084  command
1 lhr  8083  command
2 ams  8085  command
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `RangeIndex` and then create default columns names by `np.arange`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(odict, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
print(df)
     0     1        2
0  dub  8084  command
1  lhr  8083  command
2  ams  8085  command
```

Another solution with list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in odict.items()])
print(df)
     0     1        2
0  dub  8084  command
1  lhr  8083  command
2  ams  8085  command
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help. Both suggestions worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me solve an issue where I had a dictionary/dataframe:

        outputDict = {str(key): str(value) for key, value in keys_values}
        output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(outputDict,orient='index')
Thus, "keys" was not indexed and could not be renamed. Your answer solved the issue.